# re-evaluating an object binding when a sub property changes

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer

I am attempting to wrap a data provider in a custom element in order to utilize the mediator pattern in my application, but I'm a little confused about this behavior I'm running into.

Here's a shortened version of my data provider:

```
<dom-module id="archive-data">
  <script>
  (function () {
    //some helper functions 
    //...  
    var api = {
      is: 'archive-data',
      properties: {
        archive: {
          type: Object,
          value: { 
            name: value,
            ...,
            meetings: [] 
          },
          notify: true
        }
      },
      ready: function () { this.update(); },
      update: function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var data = HELPERS.extractResult(xhr.response);
            this.archive.meetings = someFunction(data);
          }
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.open("POST", "serverAPI.cfc?method=getData");
        xhr.send();
      }
    };
    Polymer(api);
  }());
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The Idea is that this thing is going to request some data from the back end asynchronously. Later, if the application makes a change to the Database, the mediator can call `update()` on this provider and any elements that have bindings on `archive` will get the updates.

So the mediator could use the provider like:

```
<archive-data archive="{{archive}}"></archive-data> 
<other-element my-data="[[archive]]"></other-element>
```

---

The issue I'm running into is that the data binding isn't working. I'm wondering why. From what I can tell, the docs say it should work:

> Two-way data-binding and observation of paths in Polymer is achieved
>   using a similar strategy to the one described above for 2-way property
>   binding :
>
> When a sub-property of a property configured with `type: Object`
>   changes, an element fires a non-bubbling `<property>-changed` DOM event
>   with a `detail.path` value indicating the path on the object that
>   changed.
>
> Elements that have registered interest in that object (either via
>   binding or change handler) may then take the appropriate action.
>
> Finally, those elements will forward the notification on to any
>   children they have bound the object to, and will also fire a new
>   `<property>-changed` event where property is the root object, to notify
>   any hosts that may have bound root object down.

**I tried: `this.set('archive.meetings', someFunction(data));` instead of direct assignment, but that didn't work.**

I also tried running: `this.fire('archive-changed');` directly after the assignment, but that didn't work either!

However, If I replace the entire `archive` object with a new one, the binding recomputes as expected. e.g. `this.archive = { meetings: someFunction(data) };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is necessary to notify Polymer that your path has change, like so :

```
this.notifyPath('archive.meetings', this.archive.meetings);
```

Here is a full example from that official [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) :

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
    <div>{{user.manager.name}}</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-element',
      reassignManager: function(newManager) {
        this.user.manager = newManager;
        // Notification required for binding to update!
        this.notifyPath('user.manager', this.user.manager);
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: I stated in my question that this did not work, but after some research, this issue the correct solution. The issue I was running into was with a computed binding

Comment: better than `notifyPath()` I would use the Polymer built-in `set()` which gives in your case: `this.set('user.manager', newManager);`

Answer (score -1):

I am seeing that 
`this.set('user.manager', newManager);`
has error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange